# Ember.js - can't set a simple relationship

Tags: ember.js, relationships

I'm trying to set a fairly simple Ember relationship, but it ain't happenin'. The premise is I'm creating a football match prediction on an 'entry' model. The 'predict' action is passed the correct 'club' when clicked and all it needs to do is set the current user and the correct prediction on the entry record. Then save it.

Here's the 'play' controller. I've commented what's returned at each stage.

```
var PlayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    predict: function(match, club) {
      var userId = this.get('session.currentUser.id');
      var user = this.store.getById('user', userId);

      var predictionId = club.get('id');
      var prediction = this.store.getById('club', predictionId);

      console.log('User: ' + user); // <(subclass of DS.Model):ember487:1>
      console.log('Prediction: ' + prediction); // <(subclass of DS.Model):ember507:4>

      var entry = {
        user: user,
        prediction: prediction
      }

      var entry = this.store.createRecord('entry', entry);

      // Have tried using entry.set('prediction', prediction) & entry.set('user', user) here to no effect.

      console.log(entry.get('prediction')); // returns a promise with correct data
      console.log(entry.get('user')); // returns a promise with correct data

      entry.save().then(function() {
        console.log(entry); // returns created entry object
        console.log(entry.get('prediction')); // returning null
        console.log(entry.get('user')); // returning null

      });

    }
  }
});

export default PlayController;
```

Here's my JSON response:

```
{"entry":{"id":1,"prediction_id":null,"user_id":null}}
```

And for the record, here's my relationships. I've tried setting inverses, but that doesn't resolve the problem either.

```
//app/models/club.js

var Club = DS.Model.extend({
  entries: DS.hasMany('entry', {async: true})
}); export default Club;

//app/models/entry.js

var Entry = DS.Model.extend({
  prediction: DS.belongsTo('club', {async: true}),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true})
}); export default Entry;

//app/models/user.js

var User = DS.Model.extend({
  entries: DS.hasMany('entry', {async: true})
}); export default User;
```

And proof I'm not goofing it up on the backend:

```
// Entries controller

class Api::EntriesController < Api::BaseController
  def create
    entry = Entry.new(entry_params)

    if entry.save
      render json: entry, status: :created
    else
      respond_with entry
    end
  end

  private
  def entry_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:id, :prediction_id, :user_id)
  end
end

// Entry Serializer

class EntrySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :prediction_id, :match_id, :user_id
  embed :ids, include: true
end
```

Any thoughts more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The store is asynchronous, as such you need to use `then` on records in order to make sure they've been loaded before you use them.

```
predict: function(match, club) {
  var userId = this.get('session.currentUser.id');
  var user = this.store.getById('user', userId);

  var predictionId = club.get('id');
  var prediction = this.store.getById('club', predictionId);
  Ember.RSVP.hash({user:user, prediction:prediction}).then(function(result){

    console.log('User: ' + result.user); // <(subclass of DS.Model):ember487:1>
    console.log('Prediction: ' + result.prediction); // <(subclass of DS.Model):ember507:4>

    var entry = {
      user: result.user,
      prediction: result.prediction
    }

    var entry = this.store.createRecord('entry', entry);

    // Have tried using entry.set('prediction', prediction) & entry.set('user', user) here to no effect.

    console.log(entry.get('prediction')); // returns a promise with correct data
    console.log(entry.get('user')); // returns a promise with correct data

    entry.save().then(function() {
      console.log(entry); // returns created entry object
      console.log(entry.get('prediction')); // returning null
      console.log(entry.get('user')); // returning null
    });
  });
}
```

#### Example

```
save: function(){
  var store = this.get('store');

  Ember.RSVP.hash({
    foo: store.find('foo', 1),
    bar: store.find('bar', 1)
  }).then(function(results){
    // results looks like {foo: fooRecord, bar: barRecord}
    var foobar = store.createRecord('fooBar', results);

    console.log(Em.get(results, 'foo.id'));
    console.log(Em.get(results, 'bar.id'));

    foobar.save().then(function(){
      // don't forget, foo and bar are async on foobar
      // you need to make sure they've resolved
      // before you attempt to use them
      Em.RSVP.hash({
        foo: foobar.get('foo'),
        bar: foobar.get('bar')
      }).then(function(results2){
        console.log(Em.get(results2, 'foo.id'));
        console.log(Em.get(results2, 'bar.id'));
      });
    });

  });

}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/383/edit

Comment: Sounds logical, but unfortunately it's still not setting the relationship. FYI I'm using Ember data 1.0beta3. This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146280/createrecord-with-ember-data-ember-data-django-rest-adapter) says Ember Data async create is currently broken. Could it be something to do with this?

Comment: Oh yeah, you definitely need to get off 03, it had issues with async, jump up to 07 beta.

Comment: Jumping onto 07 hasn't fixed it either. Could it be my serializer?

Comment: I'm showing it as working since 1 beta 04, if you have a client side serializer it's possible, or possibly you aren't returning the correct data when you save, additionally maybe you aren't waiting for the async records to resolve before using them, I've added an example above to hopefully give you an idea of workflow and what needs to be returned etc